# How to connect Pentaho 6.0 to Hadoop-Hive

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, pentaho, pdi

I am trying to connect Pentaho to Hive, so that I can run Hive queries through Pentaho.
I have installed Pentaho 6.0 on my Windows 7 (Professional 64bit).
I have configured Hadoop on "Bare metal server". The details of Hadoop system are as follows:

1. Apache Hadoop V 2.6
2. Hive v 1.1
3. YARN

I tried connecting to Pentaho by using connection type:Hadoop-Hive 2, Database name:default and Port No:10000. I have added Hive JDBC jar file from this web link: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-jdbc/1.1.0. At the end when I try to connect, I get the following errors:

```
Error connecting to database [Hive_connect] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver)
org/apache/hive/service/cli/thrift/TCLIService$Iface

org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver)
org/apache/hive/service/cli/thrift/TCLIService$Iface

at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:459)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:357)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:328)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:318)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:80)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2734)
at org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:588)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:157)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:141)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton.access$500(SwtButton.java:43)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton$4.widgetSelected(SwtButton.java:136)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtDialog.show(SwtDialog.java:389)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtDialog.show(SwtDialog.java:318)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:116)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.DatabaseDialog.open(DatabaseDialog.java:60)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonDBDelegate.newConnection(SpoonDBDelegate.java:470)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonDBDelegate.newConnection(SpoonDBDelegate.java:457)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.newConnection(Spoon.java:8750)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:157)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:141)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem.access$100(JfaceMenuitem.java:43)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem$1.run(JfaceMenuitem.java:106)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:545)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:490)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:402)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1339)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7939)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9214)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:653)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error connecting to database: (using class org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver)
org/apache/hive/service/cli/thrift/TCLIService$Iface
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:574)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:443)
... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hive/service/cli/thrift/TCLIService$Iface
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:554)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Iface
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 60 more
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be a JDBC Driver for Hive and you can use it to connect Penthao to your Hive Storage. It should be as simple as to register a new database instance. 
Have a look at this link: [HiveClient](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient)

1. Get the JDBC Driver for Hive if it isn't available
2. Follow the instructions to install the JDBC Driver [Penthao Description](http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help48/index.jsp?topic=%2Fadmin_guide%2Fconcept_adding_a_jdbc_driver.html)
3. Configure a new [Hive Database Connection](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/BAD/Create+Hive+Database+Connection)

Comment: Mhh I'm able to open the link. Maybe this one works for you: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients

Comment: I gone through the link but i don't what exactly need to do?

Comment: Have you already registered a database via JDBC to your Penthao enviroment? It should be the same procedure with the Hive JDBC Driver. You could also have a look at the description of Penthao to create a Hive connection: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/BAD/Create+Hive+Database+Connection

Comment: Tried this but getting below error. Error connecting to database [HiveDB] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver)
Unable to load Hive Server 2 JDBC driver for the currently active Hadoop configuration

Comment: You are missing the JDBC Driver. In your Penthao installation should be a lib folder or anything similar. There you have to store the JDBC Driver jar file. You can find this jar here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-jdbc

Comment: I have downloaded Jar file in lib. i got new error now as below. Error connecting to database [Fact_Hadoop] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver)org/apache/hive/service/cli/thrift/TCLIService$Iface


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver)org/apache/hive/service/cli/thrift/TCLIService$Iface

Comment: Can you please add the hole exception as an edit to your question? And also the used jdbc url would be helpful to get rid of this problem

Comment: I would like to know the jdbc url which is used to register the database in your pdi installation. Smth like: jdbc:hive2://<host1>:<port1>/databaseName or maybe you can tell me what you've used as Host Name, DB Name and port number in the registration wizard

Comment: Port           : 10000
Database name  : default

Comment: Have you maybe used a other port in your hive_conf.xml file?

Comment: Where to find this file? can u give me some hint

Comment: on my machine(Linux) this file is placed under /etc/hive/conf/ and is named hive-site.xml

Comment: where do you have put the jar file, which you have downloaded?

Comment: I Put that jar file in pentaho lib.

Comment: The error message suggest that the class can't be found. But if you put it in the right place, I don't know why he can't find it. Have you also restarted PDI(kettle and spoon)?

Comment: Config. in "hive-site.xml" <configuration>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:derby://master:1527/metastore_db;create=true</value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
 
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</value>
  <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.exec.compress.output</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>Property to compress output of Job</description>
</property>

Comment: <property>
  <name>hive.exec.compress.intermediate</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>Property to compress output of Map for Reducers</description>
</property>
</configuration>

Comment: Yes i restarted spoon several times

Comment: So therefore the port isn't the problem because you haven't set it and the default is 10000. Something with your jdbc driver could be wrong. Maybe the wrong dir or smth. like that.

Comment: As mentioned in one link from above you have to put the jar file into: for Data Integration Server: /pentaho/server/data-integration-server/tomcat/webapps/pentaho-di/WEB-INF/lib/
and for Data Integration client: /pentaho/design-tools/data-integration/libext/JDBC/

Comment: I had installed Pentaho 6.0.1... I am not sure what data integration server you talking about?

Comment: You are using PDI right? There is a client programm called spoon and also a server component called kettle. Kettle is the data integration server. I can't give you further advice, without seeing your installation etc.

Comment: I downloaded pentaho 6.0.1 from this link http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Data%20Integration/6.0/pdi-ce-6.0.1.0-386.zip/download?use_mirror=netassist&download=&failedmirror=liquidtelecom.dl.sourceforge.net  I got a zip file, i unzipped it and started using pentaho 6.0.1...

Comment: What is you folder structure looking like? Do you have a server and design_tools subdir or aren't these present. Could you maybe at this folder structure to your question? For me it looks like that the jar file is missing at any point

Comment: Hey Sorry I am delayed in response. I don't have a server and design_tools subdir. There are other folders which are as follows - classes, Data Integration.app, Data Service JDBC Driver, docs, launcher, lib, libswt, plugins, pwd, samples, simple-jndi, system, ui etc.

Comment: Which jar files are present in the JDBC Driver folder?

Comment: there are no jar files, but one zip file exist in JDBC Driver folder. zip file name is :- "pdi-dataservice-client-plugin-assembly-6.0.1.0-386.zip"  it holds following jar files : commons-codec-1.5.jar, commons-httpclient-3.1.jar, commons-lang-2.6.jar, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, commons-vfs2-2.1-20150824.jar, kettle-core-6.0.1.0-386.jar, kettle-engine-6.0.1.0-386.jar, log4j-1.2.16.jar, pdi-dataservice-client-plugin-6.0.1.0-386.jar, scannotation-1.0.2.jar